# pass numpy.array into a function but value not changed

Tags: python, numpy

I try to pass a np.array into a python function, but the value doesn't change after I call this function, is there any way to change it after I calling it? (a0 is still [1 2 3] after I call it)

```
import numpy as np

def test(a0):
    a0=np.array([4,5,6])

def main():
    a0=np.array([1,2,3])
    test(a0)
    print(a0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Reassigning a variable via `=` doesn't change the object the variable pointed to. You're just throwing away the reference to that object.

To change `a0`, just modify it via some means other than reassigning the variable. For instance, if this was your `test` function:

```
def test(a0):
    a0[0]=4
```

Then the output would be `[4,2,3]` instead of `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: I try to load some np.array from somewhere else in test function, is there a way to reassign a0 in this test function instead of changing one value in it?  many thanks~~